# Sending email with powershell

Tags: email, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to send an email with powershell which I can call from my bat file. Below is the code which I have right now but I get the error below.

```
Send-MailMessage -From "arnedeconinck3@gmail.com" -To '<arne.deconinck2@student.hogent.be>' -Subject 'Blah Blah' -SmtpServer  'smtp.gmail.com' -BODY "Blah Blah on Host: $env:computername "
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `-Credentials`. If you change it to include `-Credential (Get-Credential)` you should be prompted to enter login details for your Gmail account.

You will also need to set `-port` to `587`.